# Python types.SimpleNamespace is it thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, object, thread-safety, atomic

Is [types.SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) in Python thread-safe?

Giving a object of type `types.SimpleNamespace` with fix attributes, updates from one thread to another is it atomic?

Example of a possible use case

```
import threading
import uuid
from pprint import pprint
import time
from types import SimpleNamespace

workers_count = 10
total_post_per_user = 5
storage = SimpleNamespace(
    user_count=0,
    users=set(),
    posts=[],
    latest_message=None
)

def add_post(username: str, post: str):
    storage.posts.append(post)
    storage.latest_message = post
    print(f"User {username} posted : {post}")



def worker():
    storage.user_count += 1
    user_name = f'worker_{storage.user_count}'
    storage.users.add(user_name)
    print(f"User {user_name} joined, total users {storage.user_count}")

    setattr(storage, user_name, user_name)  # let's also add dynamically stuff to the SimpleNamespace

    for i in range(total_post_per_user):
        add_post(user_name, f"Message from {user_name} N {i}, message : {str(uuid.uuid4())}")
        time.sleep(.2)


workers = [
    threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True) for _ in range(workers_count)
]
for worker in workers:
    worker.start()
for worker in workers:
    worker.join()

print("Results")
print(f"-- User count : {storage.user_count}")
print(f"-- Users : {len(storage.users)} = {storage.users}")
print(f"-- Total posts: {len(storage.posts)} - expected : {workers_count * total_post_per_user}")
print(f"-- Last message: {storage.latest_message}")
pprint(storage)
```

Notice how, each thread worker is updating the SimpleNamepsace, but is also adding dynamically some data `setattr(storage, user_name, user_name)`

The result suggests that it is **thread safe**, but I'd like to check on this and if is not, why is not.

Thanks.

Comment: `SimpleNamespace` is simply ... a namespace. So what you're asking is: are all of the potential operations that could be performed on any of the arbitrary objects this namespace might contain thread-safe? According to the Python docs ([What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe)), the answer would appear to be: "no".

Comment: Yes, regarding "all potential operation". So by the docs, that means that, **some operation are atomic and some aren't**, in other words, is not up to the object (in this case SimpleNamespace) but the operation we are performing. So as it shows in the docs, do a L.append(x) is safe but not L[i] = L[j] or even better i = i+1 (which correspond with storage.user_count += 1) . Is that what you are saying yes?

Comment: That's the way I read it, yes. Although, how it actually works out in practice is another matter (i.e. just because a race condition *can* happen, doesn't mean it always will). As the docs say: "When in doubt, use a mutex" (or maybe a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue)).

Comment: @ekhumoro yes it seems like, actually I just reproduced it. I am doing locust test (load testing) and should 'share' for each user that object. now when I run 20 users, I start to see errors "RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration". I wait for a answer if someone worked directly with this but I think yea the answer is no.